# I have 2 indexes, one product and other brands in ES. Where the products have brand_id in it and I am trying to fetch brands which has products

Tags: php, elasticsearch, kibana

I have 2 indexes, one product and other brands in ES. Where the products have brand_id in it and I am trying to fetch brands which has products. But this was earlier in ES 5.6 where we used types. BUt in ES 7.10 the type is removed and we have 2 separate indexes. How can I fetch the brands based on whether there are products for it

```
"bool": {
"must": [
{
"has_child": {
"type": "product",
"query": {
"term": {
"is_published": {
"value": 1,
"boost": 1
}
}
}
}
}
]
}
}
```

Comment: Here is how the `has_child` query works in 7.10. Basically, you need to use the `join` type and store all documents in the same index: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html

Comment: @Val, so should I create a mapping structure where the join type is added for product ?

Comment: But I have a separate index for products and brands, how can I create join ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to divide your solution in 2 parts, first pull the `product brand IDs`

```
  GET /product/_search
    {
      "size": 0,
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "is_published": {
            "value": 1
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "brand_ids": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "brand_id",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And then query your brands index to get details about these brands.

```
GET /brands/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [ /* this would be the list of brand_ids from Step 1 */ ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it in just one query ?

Comment: As of now, using two separate queries that what is being used currently in my code is a common and practical approach in Elasticsearch when dealing with separate indexes. While it's not as efficient as a single-query join, it's often the best option available given the nature of how Elasticsearch handles data across multiple indexes.